# Running full installation of Ubuntu // full instalation of windows 7 in one PC

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

I must admit I'm a total noob in this.

I've been running ubuntu 11.10 in windows 7 using Wubi installation, and I love Ubuntu.
   I would like to make a full dual boot instalation of Ubuntu on my PC, because ,according to what I've read, Ubuntu on Wubi is a lot less efficient.

Can I run a full installation of Ubuntu in one partition of the hard drive and a full installation of windows 7 in another one, and still be able to run GRUB when I boot my pc?
If it is possible, what is the best way to configure the hard drive partitions?

I have a 283.32 GB hard drive, I want to install windows in one partition and ubuntu in another, but also create a partition to share files between ubuntu and windows... like mp3, video, images...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you install Windows 7 first and then Ubuntu.  Ubuntu is aware of Windows 7, while Windows 7 will try to make Ubuntu disappear.

While your windows partition needs to be very large, Ubuntu will not need too much space.
I recommend you set your partitions manually when installing ubuntu like this:

```
primary 1: Windows partition you cannot get rid of
primary 2: ?Gb Windows partition.
extended 1: 8GB Ubuntu '/' (system)
extended 2: 256MB-1GB 'swap'
extended 3: remaining ntfs for your documents, music and video.<br>
```

This way you can share data between both operating systems, with minimal issues.
I use this setting with 1 windows and 2 linux distros.

With 'Minimal issues' I mean you may be asked wether to execute a file or view it even if it is not a program on linux, or finding a lot of thumbs.db files, System Volume Information or .Trash folders. Or problems with symbolic links.

Oh yeah, and **don't forget to backup all your data first!**

Comment: 8GB on '/' doesn't leave much room for anything. I'd recommend 20-30GB minimum. For swap you need > size of RAM if you intend to hibernate.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, but i would recomend that you have some separate space for users, so a separate partition for home. There are some things that you will only use linux for (shell scripts, user settings etc).,Windows and Linux handle these things very differently. Then use a link to the ntfs partitions for those documents that you need to share between the 2 OSes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot that works fine, with a partition "/home" that can be used to share files. From my experience a 10-20GB partition for Ubuntu and swap 1-1/12 times the size of physical ram works the best.

Lifehacker did a great guide to doing this exactly, following is the link. http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

Answer (score -1):

The following Ubuntu Community documentation link will give you instructions on how to [remove your WUBI install from inside Windows 7](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi#Un-install_from_Vista_or_Win7)

You should then have a good read through the Ubuntu community documentation on setting up a [dual boot system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)